# Ubuntu 15.04 - Grub purple screen not showing and stuck at mouse pointer with black screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 15.04

I have Ubuntu 15.04 installed alongside windows 7 and I am using EasyBCD for booting with GRUB.

Suddenly, The purple screen (GRUB) did not show after selecting **Ubuntu** from the boot menu, and It stuck at black screen with mouse pointer, When I try to Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> the GRUB word showing the same black screen and stuck on it.

[image: **The screen**]

Any suggestion? Do not tell me to type commands like **boot-repair** solution, Because I do not have access to the terminal or anything expect the Window 7.

Answer (score -1):

I have fixed it by Adding new entry ( grub2 ) in Linux driver in **EasyBCD**.
But I do not know why is that problem.